# AfxInitRichEdit2() problems in ATL dll - Visual Studio 2008 C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on an ATL dll, under C++ VisualStudio 2008. I would include an RichEdit 2.0 Control in an AxDialogImpl dialog. To use RichEdit 2.0 it is needed call AfxInitRichEdit2(). I did it in a non ATL project with no problems, but in the ATL project I have an C3861 error, 'missing identifier' for AfxInitRichEdit2(). In MSDN documentation you can see that AfxInitRichEdit2() needs afxwin.h; but if I include afxwin.h with stdafx.h, I receive the error "WINDOWS.H already include"; if I trie to work without precompiled headers I receive a lot of errors.

Dears, could anyone tell me how do I work,

Thanks in advance,

Xavier